# How do I install PostgreSQL driver on Apache?

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

I need to be able to connect from my (Ubuntu + Apache) web server to a remote PostgreSQL database, but unfortunately, the version of PHP on my web server doesn't have the php_pgsql.dll library and throws an error if I try and uncomment this section of php.ini.

I've searched the internet and found lots of advice on how to install PostgreSQL on my server, but I don't need to run the database service on my web server, I just need to allow PHP to connect to the remote service.

Can anyone give me a step-by-step noob guide to installing the driver?

Comment: Linux doesn't use dll files, those are for Windows.

Comment: @Quentin - thanks, that's right, sometimes my lack of linux knowledge is a real pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AnantDabhi I do believe that this is the way to install the PostgreSQL "driver" on Ubuntu with running Apache with PHP. According to me that is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Linux doesn't use DLL files but Linux distributions to have package management systems.